# jquery validation is not working on my laravel project

Tags: jquery, laravel

So when I applied laravel inbuilt validations it was working fine. But when I'm applying jquery validations is not working and give me an error " SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'profile_img' doesn't have a default value"

```
**home.blade.php**
```

This is my main home page which has form for creating students details.

````
```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <form name="form" id="frm" action="{{ url('/addStud') }}" method="POST" class="col-md-4 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
        @csrf
        <div class="form-group ">
            <label for="name">NAME</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name">
            <span class="text-danger">@error('name'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="rollno">ROLL NO</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="rollno">
            <span class="text-danger">@error('rollno'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="address">Email </label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email">
            <span class="text-danger">@error('email'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">PHONE NO</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phoneno">
            <span class="text-danger">@error('phoneno'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dob">DOB</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="dob">
            <span class="text-danger">@error('dob'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="dob">COURSE</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="course">
            <span class="text-danger">@error('course'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group mb-2">
            <input type="file" class="form-control" name="profile_img">
            <span class="text-danger">@error('profile_img'){{$message}}@enderror</span>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary text-uppercase">create</button>
            <a href="/list" class="btn btn-secondary text-uppercase">view list</a>
        </div>

    </form>

</div>

<!-- jquery validation before form submit -->
<script>
    // $.validator.addMethod('filesize', function(value, element, param) {
    //     return this.optional(element) || (element.files[0].size <= param)
    // });

    $("form[name = 'form']").validate({

        rules: {
            name: {
                required: true,
            },
            rollno: {
                required: true,
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
            },
            phoneno: {
                required: true,
                digits: 10,
            },
            dob: {
                required: true,
                date: true
            },
            course: {
                required: true,
            },
            profile_img: {
                required: true,
                extension: "png|jpg|PNG|JPEG",
                filesize: 1048576,
            },
        },
        messages: {
            name: {
                required: 'name is required',
            },
            rollno: {
                required: 'roll no is required',
            },
            email: {
                required: 'email is required',
            },
            phoneno: {
                required: 'phone no is required',
            },
            dob: {
                required: 'dob is required',
            },
            course: {
                required: 'course is required',
            },
            profile_img: {
                required: 'image is required',
            },
        }

    })
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery-validation@1.19.3/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.3/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<!-- <script src="../js/validations.js"></script> -->

@endsection
````

This is my controller in which I have commented the inbuilt laravel validations which is working fine.

````
**StudentController.php**
```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Student;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;


class StudentController extends Controller
{
    // public function index()
    // {
    //     return view('');
    // }

    public function create(Request $req)
    {
        $student = new Student;
        $student->name = $req->name;
        $student->rollno = $req->rollno;
        $student->email = $req->email;
        $student->phoneno = $req->phoneno;
        $student->dob = $req->dob;
        $student->course = $req->course;
        // $student->profile_img = $req->profile_img;

        if ($req->hasFile('profile_img')) {
            $file = $req->file('profile_img');
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $filename = time() . '.' . $extension;
            $file->move('uploads/students/', $filename);
            $student->profile_img = $filename;
        }

        

        // $req->validate([
        //     'name' => 'required|regex:/^[\p{L}\s-]+$/|max:255',
        //     'rollno' => 'required',
        //     'email' => 'required|email',
        //     'phoneno' => 'required|digits:10',
        //     'dob' => 'required',
        //     'course' => 'required|string',
        //     // 'profile_img' => 'required|mimetypes:image/jpeg,image/png,image/bmp,image/svg',


        // ]);

        $student->save();
        return redire`enter code here`ct('list');
    }


```
````

Comment: jquery validation not working show your console error then i will help you

Comment: on console it is only showing this,  POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/addStud 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 1):

With HTML you must specify that form is sending files to server using

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

so add that to your  tag

The probblem you are encountering is because your file is uploaded into the input, so jQuery validates it as present, but when you send the data to the server, your request does not contain that input, so it crashes

Comment: still, it is giving me the same error after adding enctype.

Comment: Try adding dd($req); into controller to see if what input is there in place of the file

Comment: exactly where?? Actually, I'm new to Laravel so!

Answer (score 0):

`profile_img`  this column name in table update your column `by_default` `null` .

Then you will not get this error .

I hope you got your solution .

Comment: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'name' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `students` (`name`, `rollno`, `email`, `phoneno`, `dob`, `course`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 2021-07-02 12:15:18, 2021-07-02 12:15:18)) now it is showing another column. !!

Comment: update name colom by default null    also   dd($req->all());   and share your dd then i will guide you .

Comment: dd($req->all());   //here dd then you will get your result 
$student = new Student;

Comment: profile_img: {
                required: 'image is required',
            },          update  with 

profile_img: {
                required: 'image is required',
            }


also remove from coln 
profile_img: {
                required: true,
                extension: "png|jpg|PNG|JPEG",
                filesize: 1048576,
            }

i think there is conflict some thing

Answer (score 0):

```
array:8 [▼
  "_token" => "WyygV0eze9aCO2WQlZMVQyJsSxe6JwFUtSptF6IS"
  "name" => "Tia"
  "rollno" => "1234567"
  "email" => "tia.tee123@gmail.com"
  "phoneno" => "9854678955"
  "dob" => "2021-07-16"
  "course" => "BA English"
  "profile_img" => Illuminate\Http\UploadedFile {#295 ▼
    -test: false
    -originalName: "ten.png"
    -mimeType: "image/png"
    -error: 0
    #hashName: null
    path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
    filename: "php8E0D.tmp"
    basename: "php8E0D.tmp"
    pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\php8E0D.tmp"
    extension: "tmp"
    realPath: false
    writable: false
    readable: false
    executable: false
    file: false
    dir: false
    link: false
  }
```

so after entering details I'm getting this when I returned dd($req->all());

but if I'm not entering details itis showing another column as cannot be null

Comment: you have to show you console error for jquery validation

Comment: at the beginning of the function, dd() will print any variable that you put into it

Comment: there no console error for jquery validatation